# elasticsearch sort by score - same field searchable but score different?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, elasticsearch

I'm trying to sort my ES results by 2 fields: searchable and year.

The mapping in my Rails app:

```
# mapping
  def as_indexed_json(options={}) 
    as_json(only: [:id, :searchable, :year]) 
  end 

  settings index: { number_of_shards: 5, number_of_replicas: 1 } do
    mapping do
      indexes :id, index: :not_analyzed
      indexes :searchable
      indexes :year
    end
  end
```

The query:

```
 @records = Wine.search(query: {match: {searchable: {query:params[:search], fuzziness:2, prefix_length:1}}}, sort: {_score: {order: :desc}, year: {order: :desc}}, size:100)
```

The interesting thing in the query:

```
sort: {_score: {order: :desc}, year: {order: :desc}}
```

I think the query is working well with the 2 sort params.
My problem is the score is not the same for 2 documents with the same name (searchable field).

For example, I'm searching for "winery":

[image]

You can see a very different score, even if the searchable field is the same. I think the issue is due to the ID field (it's an UUID in fact). Looks like this ID field influences the score. 
But in my schema mapping, I wrote that ID should not be analyzed and in my ES query, I ask to search ONLY in "searchable" field, not in ID too.

What did I miss to math the same score for same fields ? (actually, sorting by year after score is not useful cos' scores are different for same fields)

Comment: Have you tried [explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-explain.html)? I can give a clue how the score is calculated.

Comment: No. I can't try explain. However, I made tests: if I removed ID from `as_json(only: [:searchable, :year])` , the score is the same. So, I'm sure the ID is changing the score. How to index the ID without influencing the scoring ?

Comment: Maybe I will removed the indexing of the ID because ES uses the same ID to match documents, so it's redundant ?

Comment: Why can't you try explain? It's the best way to know for sure what's going on.

Comment: Now I have used EXPLAIN and have the same results for both documents. `{"_index":"wines","_type":"wine","_id":"0D9AA417-233C-4F45-A64D-806860527704","matched":true,"explanation":{"value":0.30685282,"description":"weight(searchable:winery in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:","details":[{"value":0.30685282,"description":"fieldWeight in 0, product of:","details":[{"value":1.0,"description":"tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:","details":[{"value":1.0,"description":"termFreq=1.0"}]},{"value":0.30685282,"description":"idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)"},{"value":1.0,"description":"fieldNorm(doc=0)"}]}]}`

Comment: So, I will run more tests.

Comment: How many shards do you have?

Comment: I assume [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/relevance-is-broken.html) is the explanation. TLDR scores are calculated for each shard independently.

Comment: I think you are right because my tests are in devs. I will test in prod with 1.5M documents... Thanks. In all cases, I'm not sure that indexing ID is a good idea because the _uid of ES takes automatically the value of my ID from MySQL. So it's just increasing ES index size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scores are different, because they are calculated independently for each shard. [See here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/relevance-is-broken.html) for more info.

Comment: Can you please explain in in more details?